# Use table with multiple rows with the same value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to do a `INNER JOIN` and count values with information from two tables. The problem is that the product category table have multiple rows with the same or similar value and my `COUNT()` is to high as a result.

My two tables

Sales table

```
  Date              prod_id
  2016-01-01        81
  2016-01-01        82
  2016-01-01        81
  2016-10-01        80
  2016-01-01        80
  2016-01-02        80
  2016-01-02        80
  2016-01-02        81
  2016-01-02        81
  ....              ....
```

Product table

```
  prodid         Name
  80             Banana
  81             Apple
  82             Orange
  83             Ice Cream
  80             BANANAS
  81             APPLE
  82             
  83             Ice Cream
  ....           ....
```

When I do an `INNER JOIN` and count the number of occurrences of e.g. `prod_id` I get an unreasonable high number, and my guess is that it's because there are more than one occurrence of `prod_id` 80 for example.

Do you have any idea for a solution? My first reaction was to redo the `Procuct` table, but there are many other systems depending on that table so I can't change it a foreseeable future.

My query so far:

```
 SELECT 
 pt.Date AS "Date", 
 ft.Name AS "Product", 
 COUNT(ft.Name) Number
 FROM SALES as pt
 INNER JOIN PROD_TABLE AS ft ON pt.prod_id=ft.prodid
 WHERE pt.Date BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND '2016-01-30'
 GROUP BY pt.Date, ft.Name
 ORDER BY pt.Date DESC
```

Expected result:

```
  Date         Product      Number
  2016-01-01   Banana       2
  2016-01-01   Apple        2
  2016-01-01   Orange       1
```

Comment: Show us the expected result, and your current query attempt.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should fix the data.  Having a product table with duplicates seems non-sensical.  You shouldn't try to get around such issues by writing more complex queries.

That said, this is pretty easy to do in SQL Server.  I think `outer apply` is appropriate:

```
select p.name, count(*)
from sales s outer apply (
     (select top 1 p.*
      from product p
      where p.name is not null and
            p.prodid = s.prod_id  -- note:  the columns should have the same name
    ) p;
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess this simple query solves your requirement:

```
    select 
          date,
          name,
          count(name)
     from product p inner join sales s 
     on s.prod_id=p.prodid group by date,name
```